# How to buy Windows Phone app for child account

Tags: store, parental-control

My son wants Minecraft pocket edition on Windows Phone for his birthday. Currently on the "My Family" settings on Windows Phone website I have his account set up to allow free downloads only.

I'm wondering what the best way to buy just this one app for him. I couldn't find any good documentation on this online.

If I change his account to allow paid downloads, will I have to link my credit card details to his account in order to buy the app for him? And if so will that mean he could end up making in-app purchases / more store purchases using my money?

Comment: Can't you temporarily enable paid downloads and add your credit card, then immediately remove the card and disable paid downloads as soon as he has downloaded Minecraft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best option would be to buy him a Microsoft Store Gift Card (you can get those anywhere between $10 and $100 for example at amazon) that he can redeem on his account. Then there's no need to link your credit card to his account.

[More Information](https://commerce.microsoft.com/PaymentHub/Help/Show/toc_link_no_50?lang=en-ca)

Comment: thanks, was considering that option although the T&Cs for the store card say "You must be 13+" and he is younger. Is that just for buying the card, or using it? His WP already blocks him from using Cortana because he is not old enough.

Comment: oh I see. It would be good to add the age to the question as its vital to the answer. He can download free apps? Then I think it should propably work with a prepaid card that you bought for him, but I can't guarantee it at all. Regarding the T&C, you might need to contact MS for clarifications on that.

Comment: Just to follow-up I bought a £10 card, he spent half on Minecraft for WinPhone - that all worked fine. However, attempting to buy Minecraft texture packs with the remainder on XBOX One was a different matter altogether. Wouldn't let him because he didn't have a gold account.